# Grails -- PooledConnection has already been closed

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, grails, web

I use grails 2.3.11 and Oracle DB's on my project.

I have a problem with the database. 
Exception:

```
ERROR (org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter) - [99824F7C5386E5A40F94939FF36481FE | admin] - PooledConnection has already been closed.
```

The error appears when when running the following code:

```
@NotTransactional
@Cacheable
def findSmth(String Id) {
     //Some logic here

    Employee.findWhere(company: company, employee: employee)
}
```

This piece of code is executed repeatedly and an error occurs on some iteration.

Note: i use multiple datasources. The error occurs in the database with the following datasource:

```
dataSource_employee_ro {
    dbCreate = 'validate'
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ****)(PORT = 2001))(FAILOVER = true)(LOAD_BALANCE = on)(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ****)(FAILOVER_MODE = (TYPE=select) (METHOD=basic) (RETRIES=10) (DELAY=3))))'
    username = '****'
    password = '******'
    readOnly = true
    properties {
        maxActive = 10
        maxIdle = 5
        minIdle = 1
        initialSize = 8
        testOnBorrow = true
        testWhileIdle = true
        testOnReturn = false
        validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM dual"
    }
    domainSchema = '*****'
}
```

Exception appears even when i set 'isPooled = false' (it looks like "connection already closed").

I can not figure out how to get rid of this error. 
Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, a method which does a find query fails with the PooledConnection has already been closed error without any obvious reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem time ago and the problem was because I was running a method in a service, where the service is transactional, and I had another thread running process to the database, so when the transactional method ended, the transactions closes the connection to the db.

Anyway, I don't understand why you are using the nonTransactional tag in a method findBla to the database. That method should be called from a service, and it should be transactional. Therefore there is no need to mark it as non-transactional.

I hope I have helped :)

Comment: There is no need for find queries to be transactional I believe, they are only fetching queries with a single operation.